# Xamarin Forms Android 12 UI flickering

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-shell

I have a Xamarin forms app using Xamarin Forms Shell. On Android 12, the UI is flickering when scrolling on a page with a ScrollView. On the bottom of the page is a menu provided by Shell. The flickering is most prevalent around the area of the Shell menu. This only occurs on Android 12. Anyone experiencing the same thing?

Comment: this sounds like an Android 12 issue, not a Xamarin issue.  https://www.google.com/search?q=android+12+flicker